# How can two javascript objects be equal and not equal at the same time?

Tags: javascript, object

Below is an example comparing two JavaScript objects but I am confused by the returned values.

```
var i=new Object()
var j=new Object()
```

`i==j`       false

`i!=j`       true

`i>=j` true

`i<=j`  true

`i>j` false

`i<j` false

How are the values determined for the above? I am having trouble understanding.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the reasons,

```
i==j false //Since both are referring two different objects

i!=j True  //Since both are referring two different objects

i>=j true  //For this, the both objects will be converted to primitive first,
           //so i.ToPrimitive() >= j.ToPrimitive() which will be 
           //evaluated to "[object Object]" >= "[object Object]" 
           //That is why result here is true.

i<=j true  //Similar to >= case

i>j false  //Similar to >= case

i<j false  //Similar to >= case

i<-j false //similar to >= case but before comparing "[object object]" will be negated 
           //and will become NaN. Comparing anything with NaN will be false 
           //as per the abstract equality comparison algorithm
```

You mentioned `i<-j` will be evaluated to `true`. But that is wrong, it will be evaluated to `false`. See the reasons above.

Comment: thanks your answer,i typed wrong,it should be'i<=j',not 'i<-j'.since 'i<=j' is 'true' ,and 'i>=j' is 'true',so i should equal j,but not .

Answer (score 0):

Because each time you create an object and assign it to a variable, the variable really has a reference to the new object. The references are not the same so they are not equal. You can see this by doing this:

```
var a = {};
var b = a;

a == b
```

Not very enlightening but if you think references, it all makes sense.

Comment: thanks your answer,i typed wrong symbol,now question have been updated.

Comment: @penggao which ones are unclear? My answer explains all except `<=` and `>=` and I would say those are just irrelevant -- there is no good answer to that when comparing objects so they are not logical to use. Edit: just realized `>` and `<` but illogical for same reason.